# Use submit event listener when form is submitted via inline JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

We have a script that tracks form submits by adding an event listener to the form. The problem is that one customer submits the form via a link using

```
<a href="javascript:document.formname.submit();">Submit</a>
```

which ignores the event listener. Here's a JSFiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/XhLkG/

As you can see the Submit button triggers the alert while the Submit link simply just submits the form and bypasses the event listener.

Is there a way to still trigger the event listener?

EDIT: We cannot change the markup since it's on our customer's homepage where they have embedded our script. Sorry if I didn't make it clear.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
var form = document.getElementsByClassName('form');
form[0].addEventListener("submit", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    alert('event');

});
form[0].childNodes[3].addEventListener("click", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    alert('event');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using the href try this

```
<form method="post" name="formname" class="form">
    <input type="text" name="hello">
    <a onclick="javascript:document.formname.submit();">Submit</a>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

remove the `href` and replace it with `onclick`

Comment: Thanks but I have no control over the link. The customer has embedded our script on their homepage.

Comment: hrefs should not be removed from anchors, it causes them not to function properly and it also breaks the browser default stylings. use either href="#" (it will take you to the top of the page) or href="javascript:void(0)" (best option)

Answer (score 0):

try the following with jquery:

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      alert('event');
});
```

Reference [here](http://api.jquery.com/submit/).